# bool method inside a class ''Control may reach end o non-void function''

Tags: c++, namespaces

So, i have a class called Vuelo, it has a method in which i can add a passenger to an airplane flight, i must check that the passenger id is not already in the array (the array is at first with all zeros), i must also check that there is enough space for another passenger to be added (max 10)

```
bool Vuelo :: agregarPasajero(int id)
{
   int i = 0;

for(int iC = 0; iC < 10; iC++)
{
    if (listaPasajeros[iC] == id)
    {
        i++;
        return false;
    }
}

if(i == 0)
{
    if(cantidadPasajeros >= 10)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
        cantidadPasajeros++;
    }
  }
 }
```

Comment: What is your question? Is it *"What does that warning mean?"*? It means exactly what its text says.

Answer (score 3):

If i is not zero, you get to the end of the function without any kind of return statement. Since you declared the function to always return a `bool`, you should provide one for that case.

Now, you may know that i will never be zero at that spot, but the logic for that is fairly complex (I missed it on the first reading), and a compiler cannot be expected to realize that there is in fact no chance of control flow ever getting to the end of the function without encountering a return. In this case it's best to add a dummy return.

You can probably get away with not having a dummy return if you remove the bogus `i == 0` test. i will necessarily always be zero at that point, since if it were ever increased, the function immediately returns false.

The statement `cantidadPasajeros++;` will never be executed since it is located after a return statement. Any halfway decent compiler also warns on that.

Comment: And several compilers that aren't decent.

Comment: @Barmar - exactly. The variable i serves no purpose whatsoever; the code would work ok if all references to it were removed.

Comment: Ahh, didn't see your 3rd paragraph where you made the same point.